# setUndecorated() code is not working correctly

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

The program works fine, but when I add the setUndecorated code, the panel does not appear. Problem is solving when I minimize and reopen the program. I tried `repaint()` , but It's not working.

```
package testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class test extends JFrame{

    static int width = 900;
    static int height = 520; 
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;

    JButton selectKey = new JButton("Select KeyIMG");
    static BufferedImage bg;

    class MyCanvas extends JComponent{

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
              try {
                bg = ImageIO.read(new File("BGFILE"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            g.setClip(0, 0, width, height);   

            g.drawImage(bg,0,0,width,height, this);

            g.dispose();panel.repaint();       
          }
        }

    public test(){
        super("Test");             
        setBounds(250, 100, width, height);

        selectKey.setBounds(width/9,height/2,width/45*8,height/13);         

        getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());setUndecorated(true);setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel(); 
        panel.setBackground( new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        panel.setLayout(null);

        panel.add(selectKey);
        add(panel);      

   }


   public static void main(String...Args){
       new test();
   }


}
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: Does not compile…

Comment: @Holger That's not all

Comment: Why do you post this code, if it is not capable of reproducing the problem?

Comment: paint methods can be called by the system several times per second.  Do not read an image file inside a paint method.  Instead, read it in your constructor and store it in a field.  Also, never call `repaint` from a paint method;  it will cause paint to be called again, creating an infinite loop.

Comment: @VGR: of course, only if the variable on which `repaint()` is called, actually exists or the component containing that flawed `paint` method wasn’t replaced by another one immediately after opening the window (if the code ever compiled)…

Comment: @Holger I've updated the codes. Still not all, but now it's working.

Comment: You are adding a component *after* opening the window, and for both, `add(new MyCanvas())` and `add(panel)` you fail to specify a layout constraint (the content pane has a `BorderLayout` by default). It’s not specified what should happen in such a case, one component could replace the other or both are ignored by the layout manager, but in either case, the fact that you don’t validate the UI after adding, leads to unpredictable results, it may get validated as a side effect of another operation or not. That’s why `undecorated` seems to make a difference.

Comment: Adding all components before opening the window would remove the need for validating manually. Still, you should consider VGR’s comment and further, learn how to use layout managers…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

- Overriding `paint`.  It's  highly discouraged to override `paint`, painting is a complex series of compounding methods which work together to produce a the final result.  It's highly recommended that you override `paintComponent` instead
- Not calling `super.paint`, see the previous comment. Unless you know exactly what you're doing and are prepared to take over the responsibility of the paint method, call it's `super` method, there only a very few use cases I'd consider it safe not to do this.
- Using a alpha based color on an opaque component; `panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));`. This is bad idea.  Swing only knows how to deal with opaque and transparent components, it doesn't know how it should paint components with alpha based colors.  The API will simply ignore any components beneath it, which is likely one of the major causes of your problem
- `g.dispose();` don't ever dispose of a `Graphics` context you did not create or copy.  Doing so can prevent other components from been painted
- Don't call `panel.repaint();` from within any paint method, painting paints the current state, it should never do anything to change it, doing so well put you into a spiral of CPU death as it begins to chew up all the CPU cycles, in fact, `MyCanvas` has no right to be modifying `panel` anyway and the way your code is set up, it could generate a `NullPointerException`

## "Other" concerns

- `static BufferedImage bg;` is worrisome.  No body else has any need to deal with this variable, the only class which should be dealing with it is the `MyCanvas` class
- `g.setClip(0, 0, width, height);` is pointless (and potentially dangerous), this has already been done before the `paint` method was called.  This is made worse by the fact that you are not relying on the components actual size, which could cause the painting to overrun the visible bounds of the component
- Extending from `JFrame`. You should avoid extending from top level containers, they are complex components to which you rarely add any new/reusable functionality to and they lock you into a single use case, much better to start with a `JPanel` and add that to whatever container you need

## An example...

[image: Background example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    class Background extends JComponent {

        private BufferedImage bg;

        public Background() {
            try {
                bg = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/your/image"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return bg == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (bg != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setContentPane(new Background());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setUndecorated(true);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                panel.add(new JLabel("This is a label, don't I look pretty"), gbc);
                JButton selectKey = new JButton("Select KeyIMG");
                panel.add(selectKey, gbc);
                panel.setOpaque(false);

                frame.add(panel);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String... Args) {
        new Test();
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to position it according to the pixels. `BorderLayout ()` code works. but When I make `setLayout(null)` the panel does not appear.

Comment: Yes, welcome to the reasons why you shouldn't use null layouts. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify